# Find the values of the parameter $a$ not equal to zero for which

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

Find the values of the parameter $a$ not equal to zero for which one of the roots of the quadratic equation $x^2-x-3a=0$ is double of one of the roots of the equation $x^2-x-a=0$

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: Well, what are the roots?

Comment: You have $\,b^2-b-a=0, (2b)^2-(2b)-3a=0\,$ for some $\,b\,$, then $\ldots$

Comment: @Suzet I tried to solve this question using Vietta but unfortunately, I don't think it leads me anywhere

Comment: @dxiv then....  ?

Comment: @AayushPaurana Too long for a comment, posted as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the root of $\,x^2-x-a=0\,$ be $\,b\,$, and $\,2b\,$ be the corresponding root of $\,x^2-x-3a = 0\,$:

$$
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
b^2-b-a &= 0 \\
4b^2 - 2b - 3a &= 0
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

Eliminating $\,b^2\,$ between the two gives:

$$
2b + a = 0 \;\;\iff\;\; b = -\frac{a}{2}
$$

Substituting back in either equation then gives:

$$
a^2-2a = 0 \;\;\iff\;\; a \in \{0, 2\}
$$